# How to find out if a magic word for Mediawiki already exists?

Tags: mediawiki

I want to have a magic word **IS_APPROVED** which returns "is-approved" if a Mediawiki page version is approved and returns "" if the page version is not approved.  The page is approved via the ApprovedRevs extension which simply adds a pair (pageid,versionid) to a table in the MySQL database to indicate the version approval.

Does such a magic word already exist?

Comment: I can see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/List_of_simple_extensions a guide for writing a new magic word, but how to find out if it's already been written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=magicwords` will give you the list of magic words available on a wiki ([documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bsiteinfo), [English Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=magicwords)). As for figuring out if anyone has ever written an extension providing a magic word for a certain function, well, Google is your friend... As [the manual on variables](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Variable) explains, `MagicWordwgVariableIDs` is a good search keyword as any extension providing variables must subscribe to that hook.